# Cross the river with minimum energy cost

Tags: arrays, dynamic, language-agnostic

There is a bridge with 2 lanes, each lanes have **n** boards, and each boards carved a number represents the energy cost required to pass through it. You have **at most** k times chance to switch from one lane to another. How to choose the path and make the energy cost minimize?

The above is the question scenario. So translate it into code, I think it means:

```
There are 2 arrays, for example: 
CASE 1:                                      CASE 2:
            lane A  lane B                                lane A  lane B
 board5       5       4                         board5       2       4
 board4       9       5                         board4       9       5
 board3       3       4                         board3       3       4
 board2       5       1                         board2       5       1
 board1       1       3                         board1       1       3
```

In this case, n = 5 ,   and let's suppose k = 2, which means we could switch lanes for at most 2 times.

```
SO:
The best path should be:
CASE 1:                                      CASE 2:
            lane A  lane B                                lane A  lane B
 board5               4                         board5       2       
 board4               5                         board4               5
 board3               4                         board3               4
 board2               1                         board2               1
 board1       1                                 board1       1
```

> Please note that in the above cases, I start from lane A because it's a better answer, but we could start from lane B as if we could find a better path!

How to choose the best path when **n,k** are any other number?
And, in this question, the number of lanes is always 2, but what if there are 3 or more lanes?

**Edit 1:**
I write a method to get all the possible paths like the following shows:

```
  static ArrayList<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
  static int[][] arrayTree;  //store 2 arrays as one 2-demension array

  public static void findNext(int nextLevel, String path){
        if(nextLevel > arrayTree.length - 1){
            pathList.add(path);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayTree[nextLevel].length; i++) {
            if(i == 1 && path.length() != 0){
                path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 2);
            }
            path += arrayTree[nextLevel][i] + " ";
            findNext(nextLevel + 1, path);
        }
    }
```

Next step is to find all the paths which do switch not beyond k times and find the one cost minimum energy.

> Although this is a way to solve the question, but the idea behind is to enumerate all the possibilities and then do calculations.

However, there must be some more convenient method, maybe use some data structure or algorithms or dynamic programming(for decision process) knowledge...

If have any other ideas about this question, please tell me... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kindly post some of your efforts/code then only we can help..

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth thanks for reply..      but the point is I have no idea how to solve it..and all my code is just to create 2 arrays and some variables..i think it's not necessary to post here... and i am not asking for whole code solution here,I just wanna some ideas and then I will do the code part by myself..

Comment: So how are you going to represent a path? Once you solved that, how are you going to evaluate the energy of this path? Once you solved that, how are you going to generate different paths? Once you solved that how are you going to find the min among the possible paths? How are you going to print the solution? Is there a shorter algorithm (one not iterating every possible solution)?

Comment: @aka.nice Is a tree able to solve all the questions you mentioned?

Comment: @ColinXu you mean a tree for exploring all possible solutions I presume. If you have m lanes and n boards per lane, that's m^n possible paths at most (less if accounting the restrictions about k swaps). If it may become huge, then maybe you do'nt want them simultaneously in memory. IMO you could represent a path as an array like Javi suggested, and find a way to generate different paths on the fly in a main iteration. But there's more than 1 way to peel the cat, so you could try this alternative. Think how you will represent jumps and limit the jumps to k then.

Comment: @ColinXu note that solution may be tainted by the language, some algorithms are easier to express in a procedural, some in a functional language... If I were a teacher, I would like to see a solution in a declarative logic language like Prolog...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see it you might need an algorithm to calculate all the possible paths taking into account the maximum of switches. I would say you should start trying to do so without a switch limit, try to get all the combinations possible:

A-A-A-A-B, A-A-A-B-B, A-B-B-A-B, B-A-B-B-A, B-B-B-B-B and so on.

If you have more than one lane, can you swich to any of the other ones or just to the lanes next to the current one? That's something you have to take into account.

In summary: start small, divide your work into more achievable small tasks. Try to design your algorith in a piece of paper, draw some charts and work on it before starting to code without a clear idea of what you have to do. A flow chart should be helpful here.

I hope you find my advice helpful.
PS: I will try to solve this problem myself during this weekend.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could draw a tree with DF or BF search to represent all the possible path.... but as you said, divide the whole path into small pieces might be easier, I will think more about that, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CrossRiver {
static int minEnergy = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
static void minCrossEnergy(int arr[][], int totalEnergy, int currentLane, int step, int k, String result)
{
    if(step == arr[0].length) {
        if(totalEnergy < minEnergy) {
            minEnergy = totalEnergy;
            System.out.println("new min found: " + minEnergy + " result: " + result);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("completed: " + totalEnergy + " result: " + result);
        }
    }
    else {
        minCrossEnergy(arr, totalEnergy + arr[currentLane][step], currentLane, step + 1, k, result + String.valueOf(currentLane));
        if (k > 0)
            minCrossEnergy(arr, totalEnergy + arr[1 - currentLane][step], 1 - currentLane, step + 1, step == 0 ? k : k - 1, result + String.valueOf(1 - currentLane));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[][] = {
            {1, 5, 3, 9, 5},
            {3, 1, 4, 5, 4},
    };
    minCrossEnergy(arr, 0, 0, 0, 2, "");
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).